# Highcharts scatter: show value in plot

Tags: highcharts

I've this `Highcharts` Scatter:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Frequency (%)'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Current (%)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:.2f}% frequency, {point.y:.2f}% current: xx % efficiency'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data points',
        data: [
            [10, 25, 96.1],
            [50, 25, 96.3],
            [10, 50, 96.0],
            [50, 50, 96.3],
            [90, 50, 96.4],
            [100, 50, 96.5],
            [10, 100, 96.1],
            [50, 100, 96.3],
            [90, 100, 96.5],
            [100, 100, 96.6]
        ]
    }]
});
```

For each data point, I've provided a three values. For instance x=10, y=25, value=96.1. I would like to show that value in the plot right next to the points. How can I do that?

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/g47cnjyg/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your value is just discarded since scatter only uses `x` and `y`. To keep the value you could for example provide the points as objects in `series.data`, like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Data points',
    data: [
        {x:10, y:25, value:96.1},
        {x:50, y:25, value:96.3},
        {x:10, y:50, value:96.0},
        //...
    ]
}]
```

And then you can use the built in `dataLabels` to show the value next to the point, like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.point.value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/g47cnjyg/2/) of how that would look.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly as needed.